# How to set or modify a task to be due end of day tomorrow with taskwarrior?

Tags: taskwarrior

I would like to set the deadline for a task to be end of day tomorrow. The following was my first attempt:

```
task add 'Ask question about tw on StackOverflow' due:tomorrow eod
```

That fails, resulting in `eod` being appended to the description:

```
21 4s                                   14h Ask question about tw on StackOverflow eod              8.52
```

Is there a concise way of doing that? From the docs it seems hardcoding the date/time may be the only way: https://taskwarrior.org/docs/dates.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
task add 'Ask question about tw on StackOverflow' due:tomorrow+24h
```

Note that you can also abbreviate `tomorrow` with `tom` which would make the command

```
task add 'Ask question about tw on StackOverflow' due:tom+24h
```

See [`calc` command documentation](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/commands/calc.html) for more examples of the uses of arithmetic operators in Taskwarrior.